# Replacing an char array with another

Tags: c++, arrays, char

First time actually posting on here, quite excited hehe..

So we got this task from school to make a hangman game. I've done most of the difficult things, but there is one thing I can't seem to solve and google couldn't find the answer for me either, so here I am.

```
`int guess()
{
    char letter[0];
    int tries=0;
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        meme[i]='_';
    }
    cout<<meme;
    cout<<"Guess a letter: ";
    cin>>letter;
    while(strlen(letter) >= 2)
    {
        cout<<"Guess a letter: ";
        cin>>letter;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        if(letter[0]==word[i])
        {
            meme[i]=letter[0];
        }
        else
        {
            //Fel bokstav
        }
        cout<<meme;
    }
}`
```

"Meme" is the blank spaces, and what happens is that when I enter a correct letter, instead of replacing the '_'s in the char "Meme", I get something in the line of this (let's say the word is meme):

"Guess a letter: m"

"m___m___m_m_m_m_"

If anyone could help me out with this problem I'd be truly greatful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not an answer but an observation: do you have to use char arrays? There are three possible answers:
yes - show your teacher lecture from CppCon 2015: "Stop teaching C"; no - I want to for educational purposes - it's okay; no - the use std::string.

Comment: Your `char letter[0]` is incorrect here: You are creating char array of 0 size. After that, you want to save there something using `std::cin` and you even check `while(strlen(letter) >= 2)` which never becomes true.
Side note: Does your teacher restrict you to use char arrays, or you can use an STL library? You are mixing C and C++ this way. Using `std::string` instead of char array would be much easier and would result in much better code readability.

Comment: Your comment is partially wrong. `char letter[0]` is indeed incorrect, partly because it makes the program ill-formed. `strlen(letter) >= 2` never being true is incorrect. `strlen(letter)` has undefined behaviour because `letter` cannot possibly contain a null terminated string, which is a precondition. As such, the program can have any behaviour, including but not limited to returning `strlen(letter)` greater than 1.

Comment: ProXicT, I think we are allowed to use STL library, she just doesn't want us to use strings as she believes we have not learnt object orientation yet. And everyone is telling me I can't create an char array of size 0, buuuut, it's working exactly like I want it to work.. What's the downside of making such mistake?

Comment: Unstable code. You will always be writing outside the bounds of the array which triggers undefined behaviour. The results of undefined behaviour are, as you should suspect from the name, undefined. Maybe it will do what you want. Maybe it won't. Maybe it will make your computer grow legs and eat the neighbour's cat.

Comment: Hmmm.. My neighbour's cat is kinda cute. I guess there is only one thing to do B)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you do `cout << meme` **inside** your `for` loop. Because of that `meme` is printed once per character in your string (so four times). To fix it, just move `cout << meme` one line below, like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
{
    if(letter[0]==word[i])
    {
        meme[i]=letter[0];
    }
    else
    {
        //Fel bokstav
    }
}
cout<<meme;
```

Answer (score 2):

One problem I see is this: `char letter[0]`. This will be an empty array. I imagine you'd like to do something like `char letter[100]` instead.

Comment: that's true, not standard, but some compiler won't even warn you unless you specify `-pedantic`, at least gcc.